# Getting column index of clicked column of listview

Tags: listview, vb6

I did not find a native procedure to retrieve the index of the column, the info that is here:

```
ListView1.ListItems.Item (ListView1.SelectedItem.Index) .ListSubItems (HERE)
```

I know how to get the index of the line like this:

```
ListView1.SelectedItem.Index
```

I know how to recover the position of the mouse like this:

```
Private Sub ListView1_MouseUp (ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
                               ByVal x As stdole.OLE_XPOS_PIXELS, _
                               ByVal y As stdole.OLE_YPOS_PIXELS)
```

I think it should be possible to find this index.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You have the `ListView.ColumnHeaders` collection, and each `ColumnHeader` has the `Left` property.

Comment: i try this but is not good : `Dim u As Integer, colonne As Integer
For u = 1 To ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Count
    If ListView1.ColumnHeaders(u).Left = x Then
        colonne = u
        Exit For
    End If
        If ListView1.ColumnHeaders(u).Left > x Then
        colonne = u - 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next u`

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use a listview as a grid.  When you select an item in a listview, you should only need to know that the entire row is selected, not a specific column.  Why not use flexgrid instead?  It's not that complicated.

Comment: if i add 'CLng (x) - (16 * (CLng (u) - 1))' it's more just. but not realy preci. i think that it's the icon

Comment: This has all looks of an X-Y problem. If you need a grid, use a grid.

Answer (score 1):

The native way is using LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST.

Module:

```
Private Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type

Private Type LVHITTESTINFO
    pt As POINTAPI
    flags As Long
    iItem As Long
    iSubItem  As Long
End Type

Private Const LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST As Long = &H1039
Private Const LVHT_ONITEM        As Long = &HE

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageW" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
```

Form:

```
Private Sub yourListView_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Dim hitTest As LVHITTESTINFO

    With hitTest
        .flags = LVHT_ONITEM
        .pt.X = (X \ Screen.TwipsPerPixelX)
        .pt.Y = (Y \ Screen.TwipsPerPixelY)
    End With

    SendMessage yourListView.hwnd, LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST, 0, hitTest

    If (hitTest.iItem < 0) Then Exit Sub

    If hitTest.iSubItem = 0 Then
        MsgBox yourListView.ListItems(hitTest.iItem + 1).Text
    Else
        MsgBox yourListView.ListItems(hitTest.iItem + 1).SubItems(hitTest.iSubItem)
    End If
End Sub
```